# Почему не вызывается функция из консоли браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу нижеследующий код. При загрузке страницы в консоль попадает `111`.

Но если я в консоле пишу `test(222);`, то `test is not defined`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  test(111);

  function test(number) {
    console.log(number)
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div onclick="test(111)">Start</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код в консоли браузера выполняется в глобальной области видимости. Функция `test` - локальная, видна только внутри анонимного обработчика события `ready` и в глобальной области видимости недоступна.

> как сделать глобальной

```js
function test(number) {
  console.log(number)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  test(111);
});

test(222);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="test(333)">Start</div>
```

или

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.test = function(number) {
    console.log(number)
  }

  test(111);
});
setTimeout(function(){test(222);}, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="test(333)">Start</div>
```

Вы можете оставить ваши функции спрятанными внутри анонимной функции, но тогда назначать их в качестве обработчиков событий надо в коде, а не в атрибутах html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function test(number) {
    console.log(number)
  }

  test(111);
  
  $(".clickable").click(function(){
    test($(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable" data-value="333">Start</div>
<div class="clickable" data-value="444">Finish</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать глобальной?

Comment: но у меня вокруг этой функции и многих других используется обертка jQuery(function ($) {.... так как приходится выбирать много элементов и делать ajax запросы... выходит мне нужно то где я работаю с jquery оставить в этой обертке а фсе глобальные функции вынести за нее...? Нет ли способа оставить все внутри но оставить сделать функции внутри глобальными?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов Посмотрите добавление к ответу.